# Remove Save Video option from UIActivity Controler

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, swift2

I want to remove save video option from UIActivity Controller
I can remove save image option using excluding [.saveToCameraRoll] option.

Here is a snap shot

[image]

I have save video in localpath ,& when I share that video from that path ,UIActivity Controller displays "Save Video" options.

I have to remove this any how .coz apple rejects my app for this reason.

```
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [media as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = self
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.saveToCameraRoll]
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
        print("activity: \(activity), success: \(success), items: \(items), error: \(error)")

        if success
        {
            if AppUtility.getAppDelegate().defaultpoints != 0  {

                _ = self.getFinalRewardPoints(curentpoints: AppUtility.getAppDelegate().defaultpoints!, restPoint: Double(RewardedPoints.sharedatapoint))

            }
        }
    }

    if let controller : MyCollectionControler = self.getViewControllerFromSubView() as? MyCollectionControler
    {
        controller.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: exclude this and pass exclude array to UIActivity Controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [
    UIActivityType.assignToContact,
    UIActivityType.print,
    UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
    UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
    UIActivityType.openInIBooks,
    UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"),
    UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"),
]
present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I exclude .saveToCameraRoll already ,it's working on images. But when i share a video it's not working .."Save Video" option comes.

Comment: @Ravi: UIActivityType has been replaced by UIActivity.ActivityType as of the time of this writing.

Answer (score -1):

Please share your code and iOS version because i did not get save video tab.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test Str",@"Test Str"] applicationActivities:nil];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityVc animated:true completion:nil];
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG9HX.jpg)

Comment: I saved video in localpath ,& when I share that video from that path ,UIActivity Controller displays "Save Video" options.